# How to resolve unknown host exception while connecting to mongodb atlas?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Here is my code:

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
    "mongodb+srv://new-user_31:password@cluster0.6xvdy.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
```

I coped URL from mongodb atlas. I am using java client 3.10.1.

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: cluster0.6xvdy.mongodb.net: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster0.6xvdy.mongodb.net: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203)
    ... 5 more
```

What could be wrong ?

Comment: If it runs on Atlas, you might want to check the network settings and make the database publicly available.

Comment: Test connection with mongo shell.